# Calculate percentages in SQL based on data in the same column, for every two rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For the following view, I need to calculate the percentage of errors per day. How would I merge every two rows into one, displaying a percentage of the 404 errors out of the total of each pair?

```
    DATE    |    STATUS     |    TOTAL    

 2017-01-01   200 OK            250
 2017-01-01   404 NOT FOUND     180
 2017-01-02   200 OK            700
 2017-01-02   404 NOT FOUND     25
```

I would like to return this as:

```
    DATE    |    ERRORS (percent)     

 2017-01-01      41.8
 2017-01-02      3.4
```

I have tried all kinds of parenthesis and counts, but everything I try throws different errors for syntax, or just ends up hanging and not returning anything.

I started learning SQL yesterday - I have seen similar questions answered for merging two rows into one, but I could not seem to find one for this particular situation where *every* two rows were merged.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Select DATE
 , SUM ( 
 CASE WHEN STATUS IN ('404 NOT FOUND', 'OTHER ERROR STATUSES' ) 
 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) -- NUMERATOR - Counts Any Errors
 / 
( COUNT(*) * 1.0 ) -- DENOMINATOR - Counts All Rows 
AS ERRORS   
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a Common Table Expression (CTE) that calculates the total for each day and then join this to just the table filtered for just '404 NOT FOUND'

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
DATE,
SUM(TOTAL) as day_total
FROM Table
GROUP BY DATE
)
SELECT 
T1.DATE,
(T1.TOTAL/CTE.day_total) AS ERRORS
FROM Table AS T1
LEFT JOIN CTE ON T1.DATE=CTE.DATE
WHERE T1.STATUS='404 NOT FOUND';
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried something like this,

```
SELECT DATE, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE STATUS IN ('404 NOT FOUND', 
'OTHER ERROR STATUSES')) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) * 100 AS ERRORS_PERCENT  
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY DATE;
```